# How to set signal to a button of the GtkColorChooserDialog composite widget?

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, glade

[image: Default GtkColorChooserDialog]

I am using Glade to create GUI. I have the default GtkColorChooserDialog.
How to set signals to the Select and Cancel button `clicked` event.
These two buttons are grouped in one `GtkButtonBox` and I can only choose the box, but not the buttons themselves.

If I can't select the button then how to assign action to the `clicked` signal?

Comment: Do you _really_ need to handle actual clicked signals on the buttons or is it enough to get the users choice (via the response signal or gtk_dialog_run() return value)?

Comment: @jku I just need to get the user choice! But how to do this? Also, just for the sake of knowledge, is it possible to handle click event on one of those buttons?

Comment: @jku Aha I'll use the dialog `response` signal to return the value of the chosen color and to hide the dialog. Though, why those buttons are present in the dialog?

Comment: In  order to receive the response signal :)

Comment: @JoséFonte Yes it is clear now. As `response_id` I have to use GTK_RESPONSE_OK (Select button) or GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL (Cancel button)

Comment: @Pekov Yes, you can get the response id from running the dialog or use the response signal from GtkDialog by connecting a handler. Good luck

Comment: @Pekov you seem to have figured it all out but to answer the question : yes, you could do things with the actual buttons (by looking at the children of the action box) but that would be a bad idea as you'd be poking at implementation  details of the ColorChooserDialog. If you really needed to do that you should implement your own dialog instead.